# How to run 3 jobs in Jenkins in parallel then trigger fourth job if and IMMEDIATELY when all 3 complete successfully

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have three jobs that I want to trigger in parallel.  Once the last of these 3 are finished, I want a fourth job to IMMEDIATELY kick off, but only if the original three jobs were all successful.  What is a good way to accomplish this in Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

The [**Join**](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin) plugin is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Build Flow** plugin

Use simple DSL Scripts to do the required jobs in jenkins.

Example:

```
 parallel
 (
    {build("job1")}
    {build("job2")}
    {build("job3")}
 )
 build("job4")
```

here 3 jobs running in parallel phase.
4th job get excuted only after the completion of parallel jobs.